# x86, i386, i686, amd64, i5, i7, archtecture, processor confusion

Tags: 64-bit, architecture, central-processing-unit, operating-system, x86

I noticed those items **x86, i386, i686, amd64, i5, i7, archtecture, processor** from the web, from my own notebook, from book readings.

But I am really confused by those terminologies. I try my best to elaborate my confusion, though you might understand it. The main obstacle ahead is I cannot organize my mind on the mainline behind those terms.

1. Is there any difference between term `architecture` and `processor`?
2. `x86` and `i5` are `architecture` or `processor`?
3. What is the relation between `OS bit` (32-bit windows or 64-bit windows) and `x86 bit` (32-bit processor, not sure yet)?
4. The architecture (or processor) mentioned above are all designed by Intel? Is it just a open standard that manufacturers (`AMD` & `Intel`) follows?

I have searched the Internet, especially the wikipedia, but the more I read the article there, the more I confused.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The term `architecture` covers a lot more than just the `processor`. There is a lot of other hardware components that are crucial to an OS kernel. The first example that comes to my mind is the `interrupt controller`, which is separate from the `processor`, but depending on actual model may be put inside the same chip as the `processor`.

This entire collection of hardware components, is called the architecture. If you include some core software components as well, you have what is commonly called a `platform`.

Also the term `architecture` is a bit more abstract than `processor`, you'll sometimes `architecture` referring to the design and `processor` referring to the physical piece of hardware.

`x86` is a family of processors. In that family `i386` was the first to have paging and 32 bit support. Lots of software has been written requiring those, so often you'll see software with that processor as their minimum requirement. For standard PCs, the `i386` was obsolete decades ago, but it lived longer on some embedded systems.

By the time `i686` name was coined, there were enough different processors in the family, that this term doesn't refer to a specific processor. But there is a set of important features, that must be present in order for the `i686` term to apply. `i686` was state of the art about a decade ago. Today some systems have dropped support for processors without all the features covered by the `i686` term.

`AMD64` is the name of a 64 bit architecture designed by AMD to succeed `x86`. At the time AMD64 managed to be more successful than the 64 bit architecture marketed by Intel. This was due to AMD64 CPUs being cheaper, backward compatible, and consuming less power. Eventually Intel realized that they had to start making AMD compatible CPUs to remain competitive. They would however not market them as such, which is a major reason why some synonyms for `AMD64` has come into existence.

The term `x86` covers all the 8, 16, and 32 bit CPUs in the family, and depending on who you ask also the 64 bit CPUs.

`i5` and `i7` are sub-families of CPUs manufactured by Intel.

Comment: One minor addition, `x64` is the generic term user in Linux that describes AMD64 and Intel's respective 64-bit modes.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Wikiepedia mentions the following names: x86-64, x64, x86_64, AMD64, IA-32e, EM64T. All of them are referring to the same architecture. Picking among them is driven by marketing or personal preference, except from cases where you have to follow somebody else's convention due to software compatibility reasons. Of the various terms my personal preference is AMD64, because I think AMD deserves credit for their effort in striking just the right balance between preserving backward compatibility and getting rid of legacy cruft.